# Is there a tool to get the code coverage for each JUnit test of a project?

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage

Does anybody know a way to get a report of the Java code covered by each JUnit test in a project (or a file) ?

I was interested in JaCoCo, but it doesn't deal with tests case by case.

If someone already made research on that, I'm interested to know the interesting ways you found. Maybe someone succeeded to do it with JaCoCo and I'm interested to know how, because I'm quite lost with this technology...

Comment: You can try with Cobertura - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-cobertura/.

Comment: Isn't this just a degenerate use of putting each JUnit test into a separate test class and run them using e.g. Cobertura or Emma? Sounds like a pretty narrow use case, so I would be surprised if this exists.

Comment: You are probably right. What is the best way to catch each JUnit test and then put them into a separate test class ? Is there an efficient parser ?

Comment: In order to ensure that any infrastructure a test needs is present, I would copy the whole file and them remove all except one test. If using Junit 4, it may just be a matter of commenting out all except one test annotation for each run.